# Flatlist not rerendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList and it is not rerendering when a state change happens. How do I get a FlatList to rerender?

```
 _renderItem = ({item}) => {
    if(item=='null'){
      return <Text>Item is null</Text>
    }else{
      return <Text>Item is not null</Text>
    }    
};

render(){
 return(
  <FlatList
   data={this.state.itemList}   
   renderItem={this._renderItem}      
  />

 )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the state change is happening? Can you show that code?

Comment: Don't forget that `null` is not the same as `'null'`

Comment: Yes I realize null is not the same as null and the state is set like this.setState({ItemList: array})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.itemList}   
      extraData={this.state}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}      
    />
  )
}
```

The FlatList component needs extraData to be set to this.state so that it will update when it changes.

See the documentation for more details:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: Please explain in your answer what you changed and why it solves the problem :)

Comment: Thank you but still didnt work when I put _renderItem on top.

Comment: Yes I put it above both the render and return method.

Comment: In my case, extraData is already above renderItem but not working. Can you tell me a possible solution, please?